# Who decides the RAID levels and architecture?

Tags: operating-systems, raid, storage, disk-space

Is there some governing body that comes up with the specifications for different [RAID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAID) levels?

If not, how are they decided?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.storagereview.com/guide/index_perf_raid_levels.html

There is (or was) an advisory board according to many sources online but their website isn't online anymore. You can find many graphical explanations for different RAID levels online. The Storage Review link does include a real deal about many details.

Answer (score 0):

The original RAID levels (1-5) were defined in the research paper that
first defined/invented RAID
(http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~garth/RAIDpaper/Patterson88.pdf)

Further levels (RAID0, 6, 1+0 etc) have been coined in a somewhat
ad-hoc fashion as researchers or companies have introduced these
variants. AFAIK there's no organization that have ever standardized
these terms, they have just become de-facto standard terms.